# $v(n!)＝\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} [\dfrac{n}{p^i}]v(p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, valuation-theory

Let $R$ be a discrete valuation ring that is complete with respect to its maximal ideal $M$,and let $v$ be the valuation on $R$.
And $p$ be a prime.
And we assume $0＜v(p)＜∞$.

Why equality  $v(n!)＝\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} [\dfrac{n}{p^i}]v(p)$ holds?

I know this is true if $v$ is p-adic valuation, this case is elementary.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $v$ isn't the $p$-adic valuation, then what is it, and then what is $p$ in the equation?

Comment: $v: K\to \mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\} $ which satisfies some conditions, not necessarily p-adic valuation.

Comment: Well for instance if $v$ is the $q$-adic valuation for a distinct prime $q\ne p$, then the equation says $v_q(n!)=0$ which is wrong, no?

Comment: Thank you, I should have add condition  $0＜v（p）＜∞$、so I edited.

Comment: And $K$ is a number field I take it? Doesn't your condition imply $v$ is a $P$-adic valuation for some prime (ideal) $P$ lying over $p$, in which case $v_P(x)=v_P(p)v_p(x)$ holds for all rational integers $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n! = \prod_{q^k} q^{\lfloor n/q^k \rfloor }$

$v(p)>0$ gives that $v(q)=0$ for $q\ne p$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but why v(p)＞0 implies v(q)＝0 for q≠p?

Comment: Because otherwise you'd get $v(1)=v(ap+bq)\ge \min(v(ap),v(bq))>0$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand it.